# Figures and Subfigures in LaTex

Tags: floats, subfloats

I use the following header files.

```
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx} % subcaption for subfigure environment
\usepackage{caption}
```

I want to print *subfigures* and I used the following code.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{Chapter-5/figures/53.jpg}}
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{Chapter-5/figures/54.jpg}} 
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{Chapter-5/figures/55.jpg}} 
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{Chapter-5/figures/51.jpg}} 
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{Chapter-5/figures/52.jpg}} 
    \caption{(a) Release cost (b) WIP-holding cost (c) Production cost (d) FGI-holding cost (e) FGI-backorder cost}
    \label{fig:costbar}
\end{figure}
```

Can someone assist with the *subfigures* with individual figure names and why I get errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please provide a single block of code containing a Minimal Working (=compilable) Example. Also, remember that `subfig` is a very old, very obsolete package that should no longer be used. And which errors are you getting?

Comment: Also, subfig is incompatible with subcaption.  OTOH, subcaption supports \subfloat.  Simply replace \subfigure with \subfloat and everything should work the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelsep=period, subrefformat=brace}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\label{fig:image1}}
    \end{subfigure}
\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\label{fig:image2}}
    \end{subfigure}
\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{\label{fig:image3}}
    \end{subfigure}
\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\label{fig:image4}}
    \end{subfigure}
\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\label{fig:image5}}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{\subref{fig:image1} Picture 1, \subref{fig:image2} picture 2, \subref{fig:image3} picture 3, \subref{fig:image4} picture 4, \subref{fig:image5} picture 5.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I put pictures side-by-side, so they're small, but by adjusting `0.16\textwidth` (available width) and `width` (actual width) for each image, you can tweak it to taste.

Also, `\quad` is used to add some space between each image, you can replace with anything you want, including `\\` if you want pictures on different lines.

Result:
[image: Result]

Edit: added the two `\captionsetup` lines to tweak the appearence of the captions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grahicx](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and [subcaption](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). Each subfigure can be referenced and captioned

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50mm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
            \caption{This is a very long caption for such a little figure, will the captions overlap?}
            \label{fig:fig-a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
            \caption{This is a very long caption for such a little figure, will the captions overlap?}
            \label{fig:fig-b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50mm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
            \caption{This is a very long caption for such a little figure, will the captions overlap?}
            \label{fig:fig-c}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
            \caption{This is a very long caption for such a little figure, will the captions overlap?}
            \label{fig:fig-d}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{A lot of subfigures inside one figure}
        \label{fig:my-fig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]